wxPython widget position relative to another widget
I am trying to create a dynamic "predictive" listbox below a SearchCtrl widget in wxPython. The code shown below is what I would like it to look like, but the binding event of the dynamically created listbox does not work. If I uncomment lines 99-100 (last 2 lines of _create_drop_down), then the listbox event works but it will not position relative to the SearchCtrl content.
This is a simplified example. My real application has much more complicated predictive text. To try the example start typing something in "data", separated by commas
import wx

data = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'date', 'berry']

class Predict:
    def get_suggestions(self, query):
        if ',' in query:
            query = query.split(',')[-1].strip()
        return [x for x in data if query in x]

class SearchPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.predict = Predict()

        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.search_box = wx.SearchCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
        self.search_box.ShowCancelButton(True)
        self.search_box.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self._on_search_enter)
        self.search_box.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_UP,self._on_key_release)
        self.search_box.Bind(wx.EVT_SEARCHCTRL_CANCEL_BTN, self._on_search_cancel)
        self.hbox.Add(self.search_box, 1, flag=wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, border=0)
        dummy = wx.StaticText(self, label="")
        self.hbox.Add(dummy, 4, flag=wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, border=0)
        self.drop_down = None

        self.hbox.SetSizeHints(self)
        self.SetSizer(self.hbox)

        self.searchBoxPos = self.search_box.GetScreenPosition()
        self.use_original_data = False

    def _on_search_cancel(self, event):
        self._clear_drop_down()
        self.search_box.Clear()


    def get_search_string(self):
        return self.search_box.GetValue()

    def set_search_string(self, search_string):
        self.search_box.SetValue(search_string)
        self._on_search_enter(None)
    def _on_search_enter(self, event):
        query = self.search_box.GetValue()
        self._clear_drop_down()
        print('Search:', query)

    def _on_key_release(self, event):
        if event.GetKeyCode() != wx.WXK_RETURN:
            current_text = self.search_box.GetValue()
            if self.drop_down:
                self._clear_drop_down()
            if current_text:
                self._create_drop_down(current_text)
        else:
            self._on_search_enter(event)

    def _replace_word(self, new_word):
        clicked_item = new_word
        # Replace last word in text box with clicked item
        current_text = self.search_box.GetValue()
        add_word = current_text.endswith(' ')
        new_text = current_text.split()
        if add_word:
            new_text.append(clicked_item)
        else:
            if new_text[-1].startswith('['):
                new_text[-1] = '[' + clicked_item
            elif new_text[-1].startswith('('):
                new_text[-1] = '(' + clicked_item
            else:
                new_text[-1] = clicked_item
        new_text = ' '.join(new_text)
        # Insert new text with last word replaced by selection
        self.search_box.Clear()
        self.search_box.SetValue(new_text)
        self._clear_drop_down()
        self.search_box.SetFocus()

    def _on_dropdown_enter(self, event):
        selected = self.drop_down.GetString(self.drop_down.GetSelection())
        self._replace_word(selected)

    def _on_drop_down_click(self, event):
        # Get clicked item
        clicked_item = self.drop_down.GetString(self.drop_down.GetSelection())
        self._replace_word(clicked_item)

    def _create_drop_down(self, current_text):
        # Get matching items
        matching_items = self.predict.get_suggestions(current_text)
        if len(matching_items) > 0:
            # Create drop down box
            pos = ((len(self.search_box.GetValue()) * 4) + 20, 35)
            self.drop_down = wx.ListBox(self, -1, choices=matching_items, style=wx.LB_SINGLE, pos=pos)
            self.drop_down.Bind(wx.EVT_LISTBOX, self._on_drop_down_click)
            # If I don't add the drop_down to the sizer and layout, the binding event doesn't work
            # self.hbox.Add(self.drop_down, 1, 0, 0)
            # self.Layout()

    def _clear_drop_down(self):
        if self.drop_down:
            self.drop_down.Destroy()
            self.drop_down = None

class TreeApp(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "Transactions", size=(600, 200))
        self.searchPanel = SearchPanel(self)

app = wx.App()
frame = TreeApp(None)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()


This works fine on Linux, added to the sizer or not. so I assume you are on another platform. What I do notice is you aren't Unbinding EVT_LISTBOX simply destroying it, Maybe that's enough.

I found that if I use a SplitterWindow, then it behaves correctly and looks the way I want.
import wx

data = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'date', 'berry']

class Predict:
    def get_suggestions(self, query):
        if ',' in query:
            query = query.split(',')[-1].strip()
        return [x for x in data if query in x]

class SearchPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.predict = Predict()

        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        szr = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self, -1)
        szr.Add(splitter, 1, flag=wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, border=5)
        self.p1 = wx.Panel(splitter, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.p2 = wx.Panel(splitter, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.search_box = wx.SearchCtrl(self.p1, style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
        self.search_box.ShowCancelButton(True)
        self.search_box.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self._on_search_enter)
        self.search_box.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_UP,self._on_key_release)
        self.search_box.Bind(wx.EVT_SEARCHCTRL_CANCEL_BTN, self._on_search_cancel)
        self.hbox.Add(self.search_box, 1, flag=wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, border=0)
        # dummy = wx.StaticText(self, label="")
        # self.hbox.Add(dummy, 4, flag=wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, border=0)


        #self.hbox.SetSizeHints(self.p1)
        self.p1.SetSizer(self.hbox)

        self.drop_down = None
        splitter.SplitHorizontally(self.p1, self.p2, sashPosition=30)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(szr)
        #self.Layout()

        self.searchBoxPos = self.search_box.GetScreenPosition()
        self.use_original_data = False

    def _on_search_cancel(self, event):
        self._clear_drop_down()
        self.search_box.Clear()


    def get_search_string(self):
        return self.search_box.GetValue()

    def set_search_string(self, search_string):
        self.search_box.SetValue(search_string)
        self._on_search_enter(None)
    def _on_search_enter(self, event):
        query = self.search_box.GetValue()
        self._clear_drop_down()
        print('Search:', query)

    def _on_key_release(self, event):
        if event.GetKeyCode() != wx.WXK_RETURN:
            current_text = self.search_box.GetValue()
            if self.drop_down:
                self._clear_drop_down()
            if current_text:
                self._create_drop_down(current_text)
        else:
            self._on_search_enter(event)

    def _replace_word(self, new_word):
        clicked_item = new_word
        # Replace last word in text box with clicked item
        current_text = self.search_box.GetValue()
        add_word = current_text.endswith(' ')
        new_text = current_text.split()
        if add_word:
            new_text.append(clicked_item)
        else:
            if new_text[-1].startswith('['):
                new_text[-1] = '[' + clicked_item
            elif new_text[-1].startswith('('):
                new_text[-1] = '(' + clicked_item
            else:
                new_text[-1] = clicked_item
        new_text = ' '.join(new_text)
        # Insert new text with last word replaced by selection
        self.search_box.Clear()
        self.search_box.SetValue(new_text)
        self._clear_drop_down()
        self.search_box.SetFocus()

    def _on_dropdown_enter(self, event):
        selected = self.drop_down.GetString(self.drop_down.GetSelection())
        self._replace_word(selected)

    def _on_drop_down_click(self, event):
        # Get clicked item
        clicked_item = self.drop_down.GetString(self.drop_down.GetSelection())
        self._replace_word(clicked_item)

    def _create_drop_down(self, current_text):
        # Get matching items
        matching_items = self.predict.get_suggestions(current_text)
        if len(matching_items) > 0:
            # Create drop down box
            pos = ((len(self.search_box.GetValue()) * 4) + 20, 20)
            self.drop_down = wx.ListBox(self.p2, -1, choices=matching_items, style=wx.LB_SINGLE, pos=pos)
            self.drop_down.Bind(wx.EVT_LISTBOX, self._on_drop_down_click)
            # If I don't add the drop_down to the sizer and layout, the binding event doesn't work
            # self.hbox.Add(self.drop_down, 1, 0, 0)
            # self.Layout()

    def _clear_drop_down(self):
        if self.drop_down:
            self.drop_down.Destroy()
            self.drop_down = None

class TreeApp(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "Transactions", size=(600, 200))
        self.searchPanel = SearchPanel(self)

app = wx.App()
frame = TreeApp(None)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()

